# Gif image not loading at runtime

Tags: c++, qt

this is my resource file

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>images/Backgound_Header.png</file>
        <file>images/Icon_Bar_White.png</file>
        <file>images/Icon_Cross_white.png</file>
        <file>images/Icon_Folder_Gray.png</file>
        <file>images/Icon_Right_White.png</file>
        <file>images/Icon_Box.png</file>
        <file>images/Icon_Left_White.png</file>
        <file>images/Backgound_Front.png</file>
        <file>images/Icon_Folder.png</file>
        <file>images/Icon_Folder_White.png</file>
        <file>images/Icon_Cross.png</file>
        <file>images/Icon_Left.png</file>
        <file>images/Icon_Right.png</file>
        <file>images/3dPLM_logo_white.png</file>
        <file>images/Spatial_logo_white.png</file>
        <file>images/Icon_Checkbox_Chceked_White.png</file>
        <file>images/Icon_Checkbox_Unchceked_White.png</file>
        <file>font/segoeuisl.ttf</file>
        <file>images/Image_Tile.png</file>
        <file>font/SF New Republic.ttf</file>
        <file>images/Icon_Back_White.png</file>
        <file>images/Icon_Close_White.png</file>
        <file>images/Icon_Minimize_White.png</file>
        <file>images/Icon_Next_White.png</file>
        <file>images/Icon_Restart_White.png</file>
        <file>images/Icon_Save_White.png</file>
        <file>images/Icon_Wait.gif</file>  <-- PROBLEM FILE
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

when i run and compile using qtcreator the Icon_Wait.gif load succesfuly.

when i run my exe in setup all images are load except the Icon_Wait.gif file. why is this ? plz help me

Comment: Missing image plugin? For example `qgif4.dll`

Comment: [You need to include the plugin for that image format](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/windows-deployment.html#qt-plugins).

Comment: thank you every one. its now working